Power shell need help removing spaces from an .IDX file
I have files coming in automatically and they come in with a ";   " when I need ";" I can't switch them at the sender's side so I am creating a Power shell to adjust them I then am dumping them into a sub folder. I asked AI and it gave me the below script which fails on the semicolon every time.
# Define the path to the input file and the output file
$inputFilePath = "Folder location missing for reasons\ivy\ridge.idx"
$outputFilePath = "Folder location missing for reasons\ivy\help\ridge.idx"

# Read the content of the input file
$content = Get-Content -Path $inputFilePath

# Replace ';   ' with ';'
$updatedContent = $content -replace ';   ', ';'

# Replace ':   ' with ':'
$updatedContent = $content -replace ': ', ':'

# Write the updated content to the output file
Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value $updatedContent

Write-Host "Replacement complete. Check the output file at $outputFilePath"`

I then tried searching on here and found a similar question got the below response. which would dump to the original folder which is not preferred but fixable.
$path = "S:\Internal Operations\DataCenter\Foxtrot\temp\_Levi\dump\ivy\ridge.idx"
$word = ";   Imp"
$replacement = ";Imp"
$content = ": "
$updatedcontent = ":"
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement 
$newText = $text -replace $content,$updatedcontent
$newText > $path

any info would be helpful!
thanks!
expect the colons and semicolons replaced on the original file

-replace ';   ', ';' probably fails because you have a TAB char there. Try with $content -replace '(?<=;)\s+'

is the number of (white)spaces actually fixed like that? Please show an example
